# Add CSS to react created elements like data-reactroot

Tags: reactjs

Under my root div react creates another div "automatically". Is there a way to add a class to that div? I need to add height: 100% to it to prevent the background content to scroll in mobile when an overlay is shown.

This is how it is shown when i inspect the element on the site. I need to add height:100% to the data-reactroot div when a button is clicked. But that div is nowhere in my source code.

```
<div id="root">
    <div data-reactroot data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="161698...
```

I could add this code in the container's componentDidMount()

```
    let root = document.querySelectorAll('[data-reactroot]')[0];
    if (root) {
        root.style.height = '100%';
    }
```

But isnt there a better way to do it? This feels like kind of hacky (in a bad way)

Comment: `#root > [data-reactroot] { height: 100% }` in your CSS should work.

Comment: When you say that the inner div is created "automatically" what do you exactly mean? Is it created by a component you don't control?

Comment: with created automatically i mean that i dont have them in my JSX.  Fabian Schultz your comment works indeed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great question and great solution. Thanks.

Comment: @FabianSchultz - I think you should answer this :)

Comment: @Danield Added! Didn't realize that this is a common problem, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`#root > [data-reactroot] { height: 100% }` in your CSS should work.

Or just the tag itself:

```
[data-reactroot] { ... }
```

Comment: It looks like starting with React 16 [there is no more `data-reactroot`](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10971). Why not style `#root` directly? If name collision is an issue, a more unique ID could help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use in-line css, just make your top div position is absolute and left, top, right, bottom is zero. 
So if you inspect the element:

```
<div id="root">
  <div data-reactroot>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px>
       ....
```

Comment: For some reason Fabian's solution did not work, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

So simple by using the id reference

```
#root{
  /* your css here! */ 
}
```