# Style for data-reactroot

Tags: reactjs

Under react root, I create a `div` and it automatically assigns to `data-reactroot`. I already searched and tried to set style for this div in any way [Add css to data-reactroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41259244/add-css-to-react-created-elements-like-data-reactroot). But it does not work for me.

[image: DevTools view]

By accessing from `root` from CSS code in .scss

```
#root > [data-reactroot] { background-color: red }
```

And add `className` to `div`

```
<div className="tablediv">

.tablediv {  background-color: red }
```

Is there a way to set style to that div? I'm using **react 15.6.1**

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions should work so problem is in other place. Maybe your styles are not loaded into your html? Styles for data-reactroot attribute unable to update react for version 16 because there is no such attribute so better way is do it with id or with className.

Cheers